# How can I test the correct text has been input to a field with Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm writing Selenium tests and need to check that javascript correctly sets the text in certain fields.

I've been trying to use `.text` to get the text value of a particular Webelement like so;

```
test = WebDriverWait(self.ff, 10).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='id_testText']"))
assert test.text == u'TEST'
```

But `test.text` never gets a value.

I can `.clear()` it and also `.send_keys()` to it, but even with these I can't get a value. So where am I going wrong in trying to test it's value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why using wait to get webelement? Anyway

```
test = WebDriverWait(self.ff, 10).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='id_testText']"))
text = test.get_attribute('value')
assert text == u'TEST'
```

Comment: The waits are essentially because I am copy/pasting all my tests and thats how I originally had things setup because of timing issues in an old app.

Comment: Does it help to fight the StaleElementReferenceException? If it does, you just solved the main question of my QA's life :)

Comment: Afraid I've not come across that Exception in my testing recently that I remember. It doesn't effect execution time and helps when things take a little longer to load etc.